# Moving 33Gb images from Shared host to VPS

Tags: vps, hosts, data-transfer

i have a shared host in iPage, and now i have purchase an unmanaged VPS.
in my iPage host i have 33Gb of images and i want to transfer it to the VPS.

What would be the most effective method to transfer 33Gb of images from a shared host to a brand new VPS?

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I would use `rsync` for this. `scp` would get the job done, but `rsync` has a lot of niceties, like incrementally sending data, compression, etc. and it can all work over SSH, provided both servers have `rsync`.

Comment: hello can you tell me how it work

Comment: You read the man page for rsync, and maybe search google for some examples.

Answer (score 3):

[`scp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) ​
 ​
 ​
 ​
 ​
 ​
 ​
 ​
 ​
 ​
 ​
 ​
 ​
 ​
 ​
 ​
 ​
 ​
 ​
 ​
 ​
 ​
 ​
 ​

Answer (score 2):

[Sneakernet.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneakernet)

If that's not possible, I'll second Wesley's scp.